# How do I get UIView autoresize rules to fire at viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, ipad, interface-builder, viewdidload, autoresize

I've created an iPad-targeted UIView in Interface Builder with struts and springs.  Autoresizing works perfectly once the app is running, as I change the device orientation.  But at startup, the UIView has its landscape sizing (as drawn in my xib) regardless of the orientation the device starts in.  How do I get the autoresize rules to fire at viewDidLoad so that the view takes its portrait form if the user starts the app with the device in its portrait orientation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually really easy.  In your AppDelegate, just send your main view controller's view a message to set the frame, like the following:

```
[mainViewController.view setFrame:self.window.frame];
```

Answer (score 2):

The setFrame call doesn't work from me - because simply calling mainViewController.view causes viewDidLoad to be triggered before the setFrame is processed.

However, inside the viewDidLoad for your main view controller, you can call this before you do other calculations:

```
[self.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```